# Additional scrollbar appears inside the browser on every page + lag scroll -Winner theme

Tags: plugins, pages

All the pages have a inner scrollbar which appears with lag in scroll sometimes .
I have checked disabling all the elements one by one but could not get it to work
Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error occured due to a plugin named 'GeoDirectory' once I disabled it - all scroll bars disappeared ! so yah if you get 2 scroll bars and lag in scroll which is pretty annoying try checking the plugins -if Geo Directory is one of them -disable it and all will get back to normal!